# How to check video of Brightcove Video Cloud playing or pausing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, brightcove

Example Brightcove video code:

```
<object id="myExperience922656010001" width="480" height="270" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,47,0">
    <param name="movie" value="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="videoId=1507781667001&playerID=1507808033001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABXxBZKsE~,AdU2xXeQoKCatdLR1Pb_eo4UzCFcjSKc&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" />
    <param name="base" value="http://admin.brightcove.com" />
    <param name="seamlesstabbing" value="false" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="swLiveConnect" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="includeAPI" value="true" />
    <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onTemplateLoad" />
    <param name="templateReadyHandler" value="onTemplateReady" /> 
    <embed src="http://c.brightcove.com/services/viewer/federated_f9?isVid=1&isUI=1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" flashVars="videoId=1507781667001&playerID=1507808033001&playerKey=AQ~~,AAABXxBZKsE~,AdU2xXeQoKCatdLR1Pb_eo4UzCFcjSKc&domain=embed&dynamicStreaming=true" base="http://admin.brightcove.com" name="flashObj" width="480" height="270" seamlesstabbing="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowFullScreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" swLiveConnect="true" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"></embed>
</object>
```

and my question is "How to check this video is playing or pause? using jQuery"

Thanks for helps!